How do PyTorch compile python code into tensor operations on devices?
Can some one please tell me what happens under the hoods when you defines some network in PyTorch and actually trains it?
class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x

# then I train my network

model = SimpleNN(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
model.train()
optimizer.zero_grad()
    
x = torch.tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1,1)
target = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1,1)
    
output = model(x)
loss = criterion(output, target)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

my question is: how does this code build the computational graph and perform autograds, also when you calls .cuda(), what part of the pytorch is responsible for moving data to GPU?
I've done some research but found nothing helpful.
I know that Python is an interpreted language, and that PyTorch build Computational graph dynamically, that is in every forward-pass there's a new graph generated.
so are there any architectural post like this one：
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compilation-execution-java-program/
many thanks!
